# How to find a string of multiple occurences in a vector?

Tags: rust

I have a vector of strings, and I want to find a string that has the number of occurrences more than one. I've tried this but didn't work.

```rust
let strings = vec!["Rust", "Rest", "Rust"]; // I want to find "Rust" in this case

let val = strings
    .into_iter()
    .find(|x| o.into_iter().filter(|y| x == y).count() >= 2)
    // sorry o ^ here is supposed to be strings
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: Why not provide a complete Rust program? Why not say what "didn't work" actually means?

Comment: You could use [`matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.matches) or [`match_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.match_indices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `o` doesn't exist. I assume you meant to use `strings` instead.
2. `into_iter`takes ownership of the value, so once you have called `into_iter` on `strings` (or `o`), you can't call it again. You should use plain `iter` instead.

Here's a fixed version:

```
let strings = vec!["Rust", "Rest", "Rust"]; // I want to find "Rust" in this case

let val = strings
    .iter()
    .find(|x| strings.iter().filter(|y| x == y).count() >= 2)
    .unwrap();
```

Note however that this is pretty slow. Depending on your requirements, there are more efficient alternatives:

1. Sort the `strings` array first. Then you only need to look at the next item to see if it is duplicated instead of needing to go through the whole array over and over. Advantage: no extra memory used. Drawback: you lose the original order.
2. Use an auxiliary variable to store the values you've already seen and/or count the number of occurences of each string. This may be a `HashSet`, `BTreeSet`, `HashMap` or `BTreeMap`. See [@Netwave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64051730/5397009). Advantage: doesn't change the input array. Drawback: uses memory to keep track of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the appearances in `O(n)` with a tree or table like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let strings = vec!["Rust", "Rest", "Rust"];
    let mut sorted_data : HashMap<&str, u32> = HashMap::new();
    strings.iter().for_each(|item| {
        if !sorted_data.contains_key(item) {
            sorted_data.insert(item, 0);
        }
        *sorted_data.get_mut(item).unwrap() += 1;
    });
    
    println!("{:?}", sorted_data);
}
```

The just use the one with the biggest key, for example with the new `fold_first`:

```rust
let result = sorted_data.iter().fold_first(|(k1, v1), (k2, v2)| { if v2 > v1 {(k2, v2)} else {(k1, v1)}}).unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f208312dd09291495a3976cc19eb650d)

Comment: This code has an amortized complexity of O(n log n). Inserting into a `BTreeMap` is O(log n), since it's a tree. Using a `HashMap` instead would make it O(n).

Comment: @SvenMarnach indeed.